# Realloc- in Standard allocator

Tags: c++, c++11

For the Standard allocator interface for use in, say, `std::vector`, is re-allocation supported? I have a rather specific use-case in which being able to `realloc` directly would be much more efficient than allocating, moving, and freeing.

Edit: Sorry- I have absolutely no intention of calling the *actual* `realloc`, I meant a function with those semantics. Effectively, I'm allocating off a stack in the background, and if I allocate more off the stack, then I can't free the memory underneath it, which is a total waste because there's no need to allocate again anyway as there's plenty of contiguous free space available. Thus, if I could be asked to reallocate in a single step, then I could avoid having to firstly, allocate some stuff and waste some memory, and secondly, move all the contents of the `vector`.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

We tried but failed:

http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2006/n1953.html

http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2006/n2045.html

Edit:  I know what you meant. ;-)

Comment: What does the word "failed" mean here? Failed to convince the committee?

Comment: Yes.  The proposals linked in the answer were submitted and rejected.

Comment: There was a more recent proposal - https://github.com/cplusplus/papers/issues/123 also rejected. I personally think it is inferior to the ones from 2006.

Comment: We have some progress with sized feedback from allocators being accepted into C++23 - see https://github.com/cplusplus/papers/issues/18 & https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p0901r5.html

Answer (score 2):

I believe that `realloc()` is not part of the STL allocator interface. But `realloc()` is always a crap-shoot anyway, since you don't really know whether your OS will expand your allocation or move you to a new one. Actual performance [is very OS-dependent](http://blog.kowalczyk.info/article/realloc-on-Windows-vs-Linux-1.html). If you know you want to reallocate, you might as well just alloc a bigger chunk of memory in advance, which luckily the STL makes easy.

Do you have a use case where this would be undesirable?

Comment: It would be desirable in custom allocators, for example a simple area allocator. Currently, you need to waste at least a half of the pre-allocated memory if you are backing a container like std::vector.

Comment: I agree but want to add something here. If you reserve more memory than you need for a big vector, then you do not waist memory at all. You only waist virtual memory which is ok if you do not overdo it. This does not work for small vectors as virtual memory is managed in chunks of 4k byte pages.

Answer (score 0):

You can put a bool flag in the structure you are saving in the std::vector to indicate it its logically deleted or not.  To delete an element set this flag to true but don't physically delete it.  To reallocate an element, look for an flag that's true, set it to false to show its not deleted and that use it.